# Retrieve numbers and turn as star

Tags: php, laravel

Is that possible to I show my database number eg. `3` as font-awesome numbers using PHP?

I have Testimonials table where people write their feedback and give stars (these stars save as number 1 to 5), now i can show then in my template as number it is, but i want to know is there anyway to show them as font-icon?

Using: Laravel PHP framework.

## UPDATE

I added this to my `testimonial` model and now i return stars but issue is all of them are empty stars and not get color to selected numbers.

```
public function tesstars()
  {
    $rates = '';
    $stars = floor($rates);

    $rates = '';
    $j = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
      for ($j; $j < $stars; $j++) {
        $rates .= '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
        $i++;
      }
      if ($i < 5) {
        $rates .= '<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';
      }
    }
    return $rates;
  }
```

[image: image one]

Comment: You want to display a `3` with a font on your page?

Comment: @Andreas yes. except show 3 want to show 3stars.

Comment: What if the average feedback is 2.875?

Comment: Did you try with if else conditions?

Comment: @Andreas i don't accept those kind of numbers and no want to show average is just under users testimonial comments. so is straight number 1-2-3-4-5.

Comment: @user2486 no i din't bro, but it going to many elseif! no have cleaner solution?

Comment: Yes just make a loop to display star

Comment: As you are not share any effort with any specific issues it really turns to duplicate question as @Andreas mention

Comment: @Andreas Please see update of my question.

Comment: @user2486 Please see update of my question.

Comment: `$stars=floor (' ')` ???  I don't think that's going to serve you very well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## SOLVED

Well as I couldn't make it happen from model I decided to make else,elseif in my blade and load stars manually in there.

Thanks for all helps.

```
@if($testimonial->star == 1)
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
@elseif($testimonial->star == 2)
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
@elseif($testimonial->star == 3)
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
@elseif($testimonial->star == 4)
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
@else($testimonial->star == 5)
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
@endif
```

Comment: It's not good solution

Comment: @mfortis : Check my answer

Comment: @user2486 - it luks like op dont want clickable stars

Comment: @Bugfixer : I gave the example in js, but What op wants is the first solution I gave. In the laravel style

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but just simple foor loop like this

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $testimonial->star; $i++)
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
@endfor
@for ($i = $testimonial->star; $i < 5; $i++)
    <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
@endfor
```

This is simple Javascript Example with for loop

```js
var star = 3;
makeStar(star);
function makeStar(star){
  var str = "";
  for(var j=1;j<=star;j++){
    str +=  '<span onclick="makeStar('+j+')" class="fa fa-star"></span>';
  }
  for(var k=star+1;k<=5;k++){
  str +=  '<span onclick="makeStar('+k+')" class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';
  }  
  document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```css
.fa{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:50px;
}

.fa-star::before{
  content:'*';
  color:green;
}
.fa-star-o::before{
  content:'*';
  color:lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your view:

```
@if ($rating > 0)
    @while ($rating > 0)
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{ $rating = $rating - 1 }}
    @endwhile
@endif
```

Comment: This is how i get results https://imgur.com/a/BU5gs    here is your code i changed  `@if ($testimonial->star > 0)
@while ($testimonial->star > 0)
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
{{ $testimonial->star = $testimonial->star - 1 }}     @endwhile
@endif`

Comment: run a loop five times and add a if condition inside loop comparing rating and mark those stars dark and other light.

Comment: @mafortis
<?php
$rating = 3;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
  if($i>=$rating) {
    echo "D";
  } else {
 echo "L"; 
   }
}

Comment: somehow doesn't work `$rating = 3;` it prints 3 and 5 empty stars!

Comment: $rating = 3;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {    
 if($i < $rating){
        echo "D";
    } else {
  echo "L";
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stars = 3;
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
   if($i < $stars){
      $rates .= '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';//coloured star
   }else{
      $rates .= '<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>';//colourless star
   }
}
```

Comment: not working, gives error of `< 5 :` i changed to `< 5;` and backs to basic 5 empty stars.

Comment: I have made an edit. try and let me knw. Style changes only

Comment: now i have 5 black star :))

Comment: I cannot find any issue with logic. check the output of $stars.

Comment: @VishnuMRaveendran : your logic is absolutely Right . You just showing no effect in both condition because there is not content inside span. Means `style="color:yellow;"` doing nothing here. may be change in else part from `fa-star` to `fa-star-o`

Comment: before the loop specify $stars=3, print and check the output.

Comment: @VishnuMRaveendran: I am not OP, I am Somebodies well-wisher  ;)

Comment: One more suggestion initialize `$rates = ' ' ;`, before using `.=` appending

Comment: he has already done it. Sorry, I didn't look at the username, assumed you asked the question.